# Uploading images to Firebase with flutter fail

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-storage

Hi I am using flutter to upload images from device camera or the gallery from the phone and to upload it to firebase storage. I was following examples from video tutorials but the videos are from 2019 or earlier and maybe there has been some changes in the code or the structure of the code. So to deploy the firebase I`m using node.js and it deploys perfect with all the functions. When i try to upload in the debug console says upload failed.So here is the errors that I get

```
    D/EGL_emulation( 5628): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1e853c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc8d7f240)
    E/Surface ( 5628): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x0
    D/EGL_emulation( 5628): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe3ee0c80: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc8d7f0e0)
    D/EGL_emulation( 5628): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1e853c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc8d7f240)
    D/EGL_emulation( 5628): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe3ee0c80: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc8d7f0e0)
    D/eglCodecCommon( 5628): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 13 0   
     D/skia    ( 5628): Errors:
        D/skia    ( 5628):
        D/skia    ( 5628): Shader compilation error
        D/skia    ( 5628): ------------------------
        D/skia    ( 5628): Errors:
        D/skia    ( 5628):
        D/skia    ( 5628): Shader compilation error
        D/skia    ( 5628): ------------------------
        D/skia    ( 5628): Errors:
        D/skia    ( 5628):
        I/flutter ( 5628): Something went wrong
        I/flutter ( 5628): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
        I/flutter ( 5628): Error: could not handle the request
        I/flutter ( 5628): ^
        I/flutter ( 5628): Upload failed!
        D/skia    ( 5628): Shader compilation error
        D/skia    ( 5628): ------------------------
        D/skia    ( 5628): Errors:
        D/skia    ( 5628):
        W/mple.aplikacij( 5628): JNI critical lock held for 17.744ms on Thread[1,tid=5628,Runnable,Thread*=0xe8074000,peer=0x74f7eee0,"main"]
```

And here is the method that i use in flutter

```
      Future<Map<String, dynamic>> uploadImage(File image,
          {String imagePath}) async {
        final mimeTypeData = lookupMimeType(image.path).split('/');
        final imageUploadRequest = http.MultipartRequest(
            'POST',
            Uri.parse(
                'https://us-central1-flutter-aplikacija.cloudfunctions.net/storeImage'));
        final file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
          'image',
          image.path,
          contentType: MediaType(
            mimeTypeData[0],
            mimeTypeData[1],
          ),
        );
        imageUploadRequest.files.add(file);
        if (imagePath != null) {
          imageUploadRequest.fields['imagePath'] = Uri.encodeComponent(imagePath);
        }
        imageUploadRequest.headers['Authorization'] =
            'Bearer ${_authenticatedUser.token}';
    
        try {
          final streamedResponse = await imageUploadRequest.send();
          final response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
          if (response.statusCode != 200 && response.statusCode != 201) {
            print('Something went wrong');
            print(json.decode(response.body));
            return null;
          }
          final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
          return responseData;
        } catch (error) {
          print(error);
          return null;
        }
      }
```

Here is what i get at Firebase functions

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na8OD.png


And the Index.js the config for the firebase and deploy

    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
    const Busboy = require('busboy');
    const os = require('os');
    const path = require('path');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const fbAdmin = require('firebase-admin');
    const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
    
    // // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
    // // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
    //
    // exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    //  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
    // });
    
    
    const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    const storage = {
        projectId: 'flutter-aplikacija ',
        keyFilename: 'flutter-aplikacija.json'
    };
    
    fbAdmin.initializeApp({
        credential: fbAdmin.credential.cert(require('./flutter-aplikacija.json'))
    });
    
    exports.storeImage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
        return cors(req, res, () => {
            if (req.method !== 'POST') {
                return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Not allowed.' });
            }
    
            if (
                !req.headers.authorization ||
                !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')
            ) {
                return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized.' });
            }
    
            let idToken;
            idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
    
            const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
            let uploadData;
            let oldImagePath;
    
            busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
                const filePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
                uploadData = { filePath: filePath, type: mimetype, name: filename };
                file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath));
            });
    
            busboy.on('field', (fieldname, value) => {
                oldImagePath = decodeURIComponent(value);
            });
    
            busboy.on('finish', () => {
                const bucket = storage.bucket('flutter-aplikacija.appspot.com');
                const id = uuidv4();
                let imagePath = 'images/' + id + '-' + uploadData.name;
                if (oldImagePath) {
                    imagePath = oldImagePath;
                }
    
                return fbAdmin
                    .auth()
                    .verifyIdToken(idToken)
                    .then(decodedToken => {
                        return bucket.upload(uploadData.filePath, {
                            uploadType: 'media',
                            destination: imagePath,
                            metadata: {
                                metadata: {
                                    contentType: uploadData.type,
                                    firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: id
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        return res.status(201).json({
                            imageUrl:
                                'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/' +
                                bucket.name +
                                '/o/' +
                                encodeURIComponent(imagePath) +
                                '?alt=media&token=' +
                                id,
                            imagePath: imagePath
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized!' });
                    });
            });
            return busboy.end(req.rawBody);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Did you mean `Storage.bucket`? You declared `storage` as a config object, not as an instance of the Google Cloud Storage SDKs.

Comment: Thank you that solved it saw it after i wrote the question and opened  the google storage docs and solve the problem thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the index.js file the solution and edited file is

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const Busboy = require('busboy');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const fbAdmin = require('firebase-admin');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });


const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: 'flutter-aplikacija ',
    keyFilename: 'flutter-aplikacija.json'
});

fbAdmin.initializeApp({
    credential: fbAdmin.credential.cert(require('./flutter-aplikacija.json'))
});

exports.storeImage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return cors(req, res, () => {
        if (req.method !== 'POST') {
            return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Not allowed.' });
        }

        if (
            !req.headers.authorization ||
            !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')
        ) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized.' });
        }

        let idToken;
        idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];

        const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
        let uploadData;
        let oldImagePath;

        busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
            const filePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
            uploadData = { filePath: filePath, type: mimetype, name: filename };
            file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath));
        });

        busboy.on('field', (fieldname, value) => {
            oldImagePath = decodeURIComponent(value);
        });

        busboy.on('finish', () => {
            const bucket = storage.bucket('flutter-aplikacija.appspot.com');
            const id = uuidv4();
            let imagePath = 'images/' + id + '-' + uploadData.name;
            if (oldImagePath) {
                imagePath = oldImagePath;
            }

            return fbAdmin
                .auth()
                .verifyIdToken(idToken)
                .then(decodedToken => {
                    return bucket.upload(uploadData.filePath, {
                        uploadType: 'media',
                        destination: imagePath,
                        metadata: {
                            metadata: {
                                contentType: uploadData.type,
                                firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: id
                            }
                        }
                    });
                })
                .then(() => {
                    return res.status(201).json({
                        imageUrl:
                            'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/' +
                            bucket.name +
                            '/o/' +
                            encodeURIComponent(imagePath) +
                            '?alt=media&token=' +
                            id,
                        imagePath: imagePath
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized!' });
                });
        });
        return busboy.end(req.rawBody);
    });
});
```